# Native module cannot be null. React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, native-module

[image: react-native run-ios]

[image: Error Description during pod install]

[image: Pod File]

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to run React Native Project in iOS it's throwing the following issue.

I am using React Native 0.60.4 . I am not able to understand which Native Module is null.

Can anyone please help me out on this. I have been trying this whole day.

I have attached the screenshot for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `RazorPay` lib, the pods for it are not installed. Try to manually install them, same as with other pods on your screenshot. Specify the path to the folder inside `node_modules`.

Comment: @Konstantin by upgrading RazorPay the issue is fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.